# Three.js animation mixer doesn't update unless logged in animation loop

Tags: javascript, animation, three.js, console.log, requestanimationframe

Very strange behaviour in JavaScript, a simple `AnimationMixer.update(delta)` doesn't work unless I console.log it:

```js
// This works
function animate() {
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
  // Update mixers...
  Object.values(sandbox.models).forEach(x => (x.mixer && console.log(x.mixer.update(clock.getDelta()))));
}

// These don't work
function animate() {
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
  // Update mixers...
  Object.values(sandbox.models).forEach(x => (x.mixer && (x.mixer.update(clock.getDelta()))));
}

function animate() {
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
  // Update mixers...
  Object.values(sandbox.models).forEach(x => (x.mixer && void(x.mixer.update(clock.getDelta()))));
}
```

Then, when playing the animation by `AnimationMixer.clipAction(animation).play()` does not play unless I do the first one.

This is very strange, why does the mixer only update when logged the return value?

I can't show all the code because it's too long and won't work because I have linked files too.

And as you may know you can't log thousands of times per second, it's stupid in general and will slow down the game.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should never call `Clock.getDelta()` more than once in your animation loop. Otherwise the delta values will be near `0` (since you get the elapsed time between the last `getDelta()` call). So try it like so:

```js
function animate() {
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
  const delta = clock.getDelta();
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
  // Update mixers...
  Object.values(sandbox.models).forEach( x => {
    if (x.mixer) x.mixer.update(delta);
  } );
}
```

Also avoid the usage of `Object.values()` per frame since it will return a new array on each invocation which is bad for performance (this just leads to GC overhead).